express js request entity too large
I added a text field with react quill in the admin panel I created with express.js, I can also add images in this field, but when I add an image, it gives a request entity too large error. I used body-parser for this and changed the limit to 50mb. Although the image I added is 2.3 mb, I still get the same error.
app.use(express.json({ limit: '150mb' })); app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '150mb' }));
I used body-parser but it didn't fix the error, I searched youtube and github.
